# catch-exception library not working as expected. What is wrong with this code below?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a JUnit 4 Test and I am using https://code.google.com/p/catch-exception/ library

```
@Test
public void testInvalidArgument() throws Exception{

    verifyException(new Operation("" , "."), IllegalArgumentException.class);
    verifyException(new Operation(null , null), NullPointerException.class);

}
```

Its attempting the verify that the constructor throws the said exceptions. But my test always fails by throwing the said exception instead of succeeding by verifying the exception.

My class under test is

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@GwtCompatible
public class Operation implements Serializable {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Operation.class.getName());

    private  String                 name;
    private HashMap<String, Serializable>       parameters;
    private String interfaceName ;

    /**
     * 
     * @param full expects an fully qualified operation name e.g. interface.operation . Parses and separates the interface and operation names
     * 
     * Throws Exception if either is null
     * 
     */
    public Operation(final String full) throws IllegalArgumentException , NullPointerException {
        interfaceName = checkValidInterfaceName(full.substring(0 , full.indexOf('.') ));
        name = checkValidOperationName(full.substring(full.indexOf('.') + 1, full.length()  ));
    }

    /**
     * an Operation with the same name as Action needs to exist. Actions are client side tokens used to identify components and stuff
     * @param action
     */

    public Operation(final String inter, final String string) throws IllegalArgumentException , NullPointerException {
        name = checkValidOperationName(string)  ;
        interfaceName = checkValidInterfaceName(inter) ;
    }


    public String checkValidInterfaceName(final String in) throws IllegalArgumentException{

        checkNotNull (in) ;

        if(in.isEmpty()  || in.lastIndexOf(' ') != -1 || in.lastIndexOf('.') != -1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid interface name") ;
        else return in ;

    }

    public String checkValidOperationName(final String op) throws IllegalArgumentException{

        checkNotNull(op);

        if(op.isEmpty()  || op.lastIndexOf(' ') != -1 || op.lastIndexOf('.') != -1)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a valid operation name") ;

        else return op ;

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Operation clone() {
        final Operation clone = new Operation(this.getInterfaceName() , this.getName());
        try {

            if (parameters != null) {
                final HashMap<String, Serializable> map = (HashMap<String, Serializable>) parameters.clone();
                if (map != null)
                    clone.setParameters(map);
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Exception in cloning Operation - " + clone.getInterfaceName() + clone.getName()  );;
        }
        return clone;
    }

    public String getFullyQualifiedName(){
        return getInterfaceName() + "." +  getName();
    }

    public String getInterfaceName() {
        return interfaceName ;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Serializable> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public void setInterface(final String in){
        interfaceName = in ;
    }

    public void setName(final String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setParameters(final HashMap<String, Serializable> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}
```

Comment: It always throws the IllegalArgumentException from the test though I expect it to be caught inside verifyException and succeed.

Comment: Will you consider using some builder pattern to replace those constructor? So you could do 1. check state, 2. call private constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used the library myself, but it seems reasonably clear why your usage would fail: your code for the first statement is equivalent to:

```
Operation op = new Operation("" , ".");
verifyException(op, IllegalArgumentException.class);
```

Think about it - the first line of that is going to throw the exception, so there's nothing the second line can do about it.

As far as I can tell, `verifyException` is designed to *return* something you can then call a "bad" operation on, and the returned fake will delegate the call and check the exception appropriately. I can't see how this would work for constructor calls, basically.

Indeed, the documentation you linked to explicitly states that:

> Catch-exception does not provide an API to to catch exceptions that are thrown by constructors. Use try-catch-blocks instead. Alternatively, you can use the builder pattern if this makes sense anyway for your application

(Then there's an example.)

I strongly expect that with Java 8 bringing lambda expressions to Java, unit test frameworks will start using those so you'll be able to write something like:

```
// Not valid yet as far as I know! (But likely to be coming to a test framework
// near you soon...)
assertThrows(IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> new Operation("", "."));
```

Comment: Right. Just validated. It works when I test directly on the method and fails on the constructor. Is there a solution to test the constructor directly ?

Comment: @Debasish: Did you read to the end of my answer, which quotes the documentation directly when it comes to how you should handle exceptions thrown by constructors?

Comment: I missed it on last read. Though I prefer to keep my constructor the way it is I am adding tests to my check utility methods to solve the problem.

Comment: @Debasish: You could always consider writing a utility method to call a constructor via reflection, and check for an expected exception when you do so, if you really want.

Comment: Guess thats a good use case to improve the library itself. Will look into it

Comment: @Debasish: It depends - I'd say that Java 8 is likely to make the whole library somewhat redundant; just something like the `assertThrows` I showed being present in JUnit is enough.

Comment: Good point. For now I am using a solution such as this  

`@Test
 public void testCheckValidInterfaceName() {

  final Operation op = new Operation("dkldj.djkalsdfk");

  verifyException(op, NullPointerException.class).checkValidInterfaceName(null);
  verifyException(op, IllegalArgumentException.class).checkValidInterfaceName(".somename") ;
  verifyException(op, NullPointerException.class).checkValidOperationName(null) ;
  verifyException(op, IllegalArgumentException.class).checkValidOperationName("some name");
 }`

Comment: @Debasish: Why does your `checkValidInterfaceName` need to be an instance method at all? I'd make it static if I were you... even though that means you can't use this library to test it, it emphasizes that it doesn't depend on the state of the object.

Comment: Jon, I agree. Java8 is going to make catch-exception redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the library for catching constructor exceptions since it only catches exceptions when calling a method of an existing object. Use regular Junit for what you are trying to do